# Relations and their fallacies

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

I need to find a flaw in the proof of the following statement:

Any relation that is symmetric and transitive is also reflexive. 
False Proof: aRb implies bRa,by symmetry. Then by transitivity, aRa holds.
Where is the flaw? And also, what is the type of fallacy?

Comment: The "proof" assumes that there exists a $b$ that is related to $a$. This need not be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flaw is basically that: $~P\to Q ~\nvdash~ P\wedge Q$

Thus in the case: $$\forall a{\in}S~\forall b{\in}S~(\color{blue}{aRb\to bRa}), \forall a{\in}S~\forall b{\in}S~(\color{navy}{aRb \wedge bRa} \to aRa) ~\nvdash~ \forall a{\in}S~(aRa)$$

---

Take for instance the set $S=\{x,y,z\}$ and a relation $R=\{(y,y),(y,z),(z,y),(z,z)\}$.   The relation $R$ is symmetric and transitive, but it is not reflexive (on $S$).

Comment: What does the symbol (nvdash) in the first line stand for, in First order Logic? I am not really proficient with the use of the symbol. Thanks.

Comment: @204 $\nvdash$ means "**does not infer**" or "does not syntactically imply".   Basically "*Nah uh; you can't say that*".